# Install Debian via mini.iso using Intel ethernet controller I225-V

Tags: drivers, debian, ethernet

I am trying to install Debian sid on a new machine using `mini.iso`. When on the step for detecting network hardware I cannot find a working driver.

I have  `Intel Ethernet Controller I225-V` and I think the driver is supposed to be `igc: Intel 2.5G Ethernet Linux Driver`. This driver is present in the list, but it doesn't work when I select it.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `igc` driver is included in the linux kernel 5.16:

```
curl https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/linux-image-5.16.0-6-amd64/filelist |grep igc
```

For some reasons, if you can't get the Internet working, you can use the [Unofficial non-free images including firmware packages](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/) then upgrade to Debian Sid.